# How to rotate 3D model automatically in helix WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

Hello I am working on project that show 3D model and I use helix 3D toolkit so I have the xaml code here:

```
 <h:HelixViewport3D Name="hlx" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True" RotateAroundMouseDownPoint="False"  ShowViewCube="False"  Opacity="0.8"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <h:DefaultLights/>

    </h:HelixViewport3D>
```

and the C# code here:

```
   void C()
    {
        ModelVisual3D model = new ModelVisual3D();

        model.Content = Display3d(@"D:\tests for projects\Em organic compounds\Em organic compounds\Car.3DS");

        hlx.Children.Add(model);

    }
    private Model3D Display3d(string mdl)
    {
        Model3D device = null;
        try
        {

            hlx.RotateGesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);


            ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();


            device = import.Load(mdl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Error : " + e.StackTrace);
        }
        return device;
    }
```

It's workin great. The problem is that I want to rotate the 3D model 360 degrees like a car showroom but I don't know what to do.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437858/helix-toolkit-rotate-3d-model) must help you. Just automate rotation on timer neither on button click. And check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940267/rotate-an-object-in-helixviewport3d-in-a-wpf-app).

Answer (score 0):

you can use **RotateManipulator** control which allows user to rotate the model in specific axis

```
void C()
        {
            ModelVisual3D model = new ModelVisual3D();

            model.Content = Display3d(@"D:\tests for projects\Em organic compounds\Em organic compounds\Car.3DS");

            RotateManipulator manipulator = new RotateManipulator()
            {
                //rotate on X axis
                Axis = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0),
                Diameter = 5 //
            };
            Binding b = new Binding()
            {
                ElementName = nameof(model),
                Path = new PropertyPath("Transform")
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(manipulator, RotateManipulator.TransformProperty, b);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(manipulator, RotateManipulator.TargetTransformProperty, b);

            view1.Children.Add(manipulator);

            view1.Children.Add(model);

        }
        private Model3D Display3d(string mdl)
        {
            Model3D device = null;
            try
            {

                // view1.RotateGesture = new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);
                ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();


                device = import.Load(mdl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Error : " + e.StackTrace);
            }
            return device;
        }
```